# Where should I create my shared FactoryBot associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a `User` model that has_one required `Company`.  Using FactoryBot, I want to create several users that share that same company.  I saw some [advice](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/683#issuecomment-248977879) which I interpreted as suggesting I create Company objects within my `FactoryBot.define do` block, which I can use as attributes for my users:

```
# In spec/factories/companies.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :company do
    name { 'MyCompany' }
  end
end


# In spec/factories/users.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  company1 = FactoryBot.create(:company)  # this will be shared by several users

  factory :user1 do
    first_name { 'Joe' } 
    last_name { 'Smith' } 
    company_id { company1.id }
  end

  factory :user2 do
    first_name { 'Sam' } 
    last_name { 'Smith' } 
    company_id { company1.id }
  end
end
```

This appears to work at first, except when I need to re-create the database from scratch in a test container with `rake db:create`. When rake runs, it seems to initialize my factories and the `FactoryBot.create(:company)` step tries to run, and there is no db schema in place, so it fails:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test  bundle exec rake db:rebuild
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

This makes me think that I'm trying to create these in the wrong place.

Where is the best place to set up shared associations like `company1` for my test data so that it occurs after my app properly initializes and before my test suite is executed?

FWIW, here's the error stack:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"companies"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:62:in `block in query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:61:in `query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:749:in `column_definitions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:113:in `columns'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:69:in `columns'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:75:in `columns_hash'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:466:in `load_schema!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:234:in `load_schema!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:51:in `load_schema!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:459:in `block in load_schema'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:456:in `load_schema'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:346:in `attribute_types'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:230:in `has_attribute?'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:55:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/decorator/new_constructor.rb:9:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/decorator.rb:14:in `send'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/decorator/invocation_tracker.rb:11:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/decorator.rb:14:in `send'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/configuration.rb:19:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:48:in `build_class_instance'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:13:in `object'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:13:in `object'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
/builds/MyGroup/MyApp/spec/factories/users.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/builds/MyGroup/MyApp/spec/factories/users.rb:2:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `block in load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot_rails-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:75:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/builds/MyGroup/MyApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bugsnag-6.8.0/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:18:in `execute_with_bugsnag'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:237:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:212:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: What is inside the `rebuild` task? It's not a default activerecord rake task. And could you please add a full error backtrace?

Comment: Sorry, it's true that db:rebuild isn't default, but it happens also with db:create.  I edited also to include the full error info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create objects in this way - they are created each time factories are initialised, no matter if they will be used in particular test run or not.

It's usually better to have independent factories and explicitly state in your tests that you want two users from same company:

```
 let(:company){ create :company }
 let(:user1){ create :user, company: company }
 let(:user2){ create :user, company: company }
```

For cases when you do not care about exact relation and just want to reuse some valid value and avoid relations cascading - there's `create_default` workaround in `test-prof` gem (see more [here](https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/factory_default))